# Increment a database value using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

I am working on a project - online movie ticketing system....
In this when the user enters the number of seats he wants to book, he goes to payment page. On click of payment button, how can I decrement the number of seats entered by the user in SQL Server.

```
SqlConnection con;
SqlCommand cmd;
private void update()
{
    string a, b;
    int c;
    con = new SqlConnection("server=.;uid=sa;pwd=mayank;database=movie");
    a = Session["timings"].ToString();
    b = Session["seats"].ToString();
    c = Convert.ToInt32(b);
    con.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("update bodyguard set silver_class = silver_class ' " + - c + " 'where timings = ' " + a + "' ", con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

With this code it is raising an exception....so please help me out.

Comment: perhaps you could tell us the exception ;)

Comment: incorrect syntax near '-2' . this 2 is the number of seats i typed to book. so , 2 is the value in c.

Comment: what is the exception and are you really sure your code compiles? between what I think might be the problem is apostrophe (') in silver_class = silver_class ' " + - c + " ' . Remove both both...

Comment: Sure it compiles, it's an SQL exception because his SQL syntax is wrong.

Comment: If you tell us what you want to do in your SQL, we can help you fix your command.

Comment: I recommend doing this sort of thing in a stored procedure with parameters (for security). It will also let you return the new value as a scalar result so you won't have to do a separate query to get the new value.

Comment: i am trying to decrease the number of seats in a table in sql server from asp.net on the click of payment button

Comment: Doesn't have to be stored procedure, a parameterized query will do. But I agree that putting an SQL query together like he does above is not a good idea. See [this article](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson06.aspx) to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL command is wrong, what you produce is this:

> update bodyguard set silver_class = silver_class ' -[valueC] 'where timings = ' [valueA]'

You forgot a space before `where` for example, and I am not sure how the silver_class part is supposed to look, because it's not clear what you are trying to achieve there.

Comment: And it should read `update bodyguard set silver_class = silver_class + [valueC] where timings = [valueA]`

Comment: Well, if that's what he wants to achieve. Could also be a substraction, with the `+ - c`

Comment: according to my knowledge in asp.net if we want to update anything in database then we have to use single quotes

Comment: The white space is not the only issue, but it will definitly not work without the space there.

Comment: First of all it has nothing to do with ASP.NET, because this is an SQL command. Second of all, you're knowledge about updating databases is not very good I fear. You need single quotes for string values. Also you should learn about parameterized queries maybe, to prevent SQL injection attacks.

Comment: This is a good article about parameters in queries: http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson06.aspx

Comment: Read the whole article please. Parameterized queries don't need single quotes to encapsulate values. Example: `UPDATE user SET name = @name;`

Answer (score 0):

You had some single quotes around your integer value. try this

```
"update bodyguard set silver_class = (silver_class - " + c + ") where timings = '" + a + "'"
```

A little advice, you should use a `try{}catch{}` blocks to handle potential errors in your code. When you convert a number with `Convert.toInt32()`, you should try to catch a FormatException. And from `con.open()` to `con.close` you can try to catch the SQLException

Answer (score 0):

Don't use concatenated strings to create your SQL statment, its really bad form. Do it this way:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("update bodyguard set silver_class = silver_class - @c where timings = @a", con);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", c);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@", a);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Parameterized Query instead of string concatenation which is vulnerable to SQL Injection.  And I suggest that you should use Stored Procedure instead of Inline SQL.